# Is it possible to declare a Javascript library dependency at Hook.info?

Tags: 7, hooks, .info, installation, wysiwyg

Below is my `module.info` file:

```
name = myid
description = Creates an ID template, Inputs ID form, Prints an ID and View System Statistics .
core = 7.x
package = CSU

;Jquery Library
dependencies[] = jquery_update (>=7.x-2.5)

;Needed to create text editors.
dependencies[] = imce (>=7.x-1.9)
dependencies[] = wysiwyg (>=7.x-2.2)
dependencies[] = imce_wysiwyg (>=7.x-1.0)
```

I know required module of my custom module can be declared in my `module.info` file to inform module users that it depends on it. How about `javascript` library like `TinyMCE`? Is it possible to declare it at hook.info? How will I inform that the user must also download `TinyMCE`.

I was thinking of including it using `drupal_add_js` but `Tinymce` is always stored at `drupal\sites\all\libraries\`. Please enlighten me in my problem. I'm a bit lost.

Comment: **drupal will automically download and install it.** Do you mean drush can download the dependencies automatically? I remember that Drupal core does not has this feature.

Comment: @JimmyKo Im sorry, I need to clarify my post. I just wanted to instruct drupal at hook.info that it needs/depends on the TinyMCE library or simply declaring it in hook.info that the user must also download TinyMCE library.

Comment: @JimmyKo --> please see my updated post.

Answer (score 1):

You can define library dependency using [hook_requirements()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_requirements/7.x). Then if the library is missing, drupal will automatically shows the error message in status report(admin/reports/status).

Also it will show the error message, when trying to install module without having required library.

You need to define [hook_requirements()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_requirements/7.x) in your `youmodule.install` file like below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_requirements().
 */
function yourmodule_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = array();

  if ($phase == 'runtime') {
      $t = get_t();
      $library = libraries_detect('tinymce');
$error_message = isset($library['error message']) ? $library['error message'] : '';

if (empty($library['installed'])) {
  $requirements['tinymce'] = array(
    'title' => $t('TinyMCE Library'),
    'value' => $t('Not installed'),
    'severity' => REQUIREMENT_ERROR,
    'description' => $t('!error Please download !tinymce, and extract it into the %directory directory.', array(
        '!error' => $error_message,
        '!vimeo.ga.js' => l($t('TinyMCE'), $library['vendor url']),
        '%directory' => 'sites/all/libraries/tinymce',
      )
    ),
  );
}
else {
  $requirements['tinymce'] = array(
    'title' => $t('TinyMCE Library'),
    'severity' => REQUIREMENT_OK,
    'value' => $t('Installed'),
  );
}
  }

  return $requirements;
}
```